# Find x, when F(x) is a cdf with given mean and std

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have a small question. For a problem in desicion analysis course, I come to the equation F(x) = 0.8 where X is distributed with mean 50 and standard deviation 10. How can I find x?

(my probability skills are a bit rusty)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: is that comma a decimal point in "0,8"? Also, what kind of distribution does $X$ have?

Comment: yes, it is a decimal point, in Holland we use a comma! and sorry, I miss formulated, X is distributed with above mean and std.

Comment: Right, that does not fully specify a distribution though. Lots of random variables have that same mean and standard deviation but have different distributions and hence would have a different solution for $x$. I'll assume that in this case it is a normal random variable, but in general it could be anything so you should say that it's normal.

Comment: It is indeed a normal distribution with mean 50 and std 10.

Comment: Use invNorm on your calculator. Ik neem aan dat die er wel opstaat :-).